# TypeScript- Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: typescript, types, dynamics-crm, typeerror

I am using typescript to perform some basic calculations in a front end CRM system.
[CRM front end calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvA85.png)

The issue I am getting is "TypeScript- Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type." Although in the IF statement above checks if the score option is null.

Please see my code, I have tried to experiment with / without using variables. The error is on the Section A/B/C Score = scoreMap[ScoreOptionA]; and same for percentage.

```
export async function CalculateAverageScore() {
    console.log(`CalculateAverage JS Triggered`);

    try {
        console.log(`Calculate Average Score  JS try`);
        const ScoreOptionA: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_testweightedaverage");
        const PercentageOptionA: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_percentagevalue");
        const ScoreOptionB: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_average2");
        const PercentageOptionB: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_percentagevalue2");
        const ScoreOptionC: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_pickascorefirmwide");
        const PercentageOptionC: Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute = FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_percentagevaluefirmwide");
        // Define Scoring & Percentages 
        const scoreMap: {
            [Score: number]: number
        } = {
            778180000: 1,
            778180001: 2,
            778180002: 3,
            778180003: 4,
            778180004: 5
        };
        const percentageMap: {
            [Percentage: number]: number
        } = {
            778180000: 0.10,
            778180001: 0.20,
            778180002: 0.30,
            778180003: 0.40,
            778180004: 0.50
        };
        FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute<Xrm.Attributes.OptionSetAttribute>('preferredcontactmethodcode')?.getValue();
        var SectionAScore, SectionAPercentage, SectionBScore, SectionBPercentage, SectionCScore, SectionCPercentage;
        // Section A Score & Percentages 
        if (ScoreOptionA != null && PercentageOptionA != null) {
            ScoreOptionA.getValue();
            PercentageOptionA.getValue();
            SectionAScore = scoreMap[ScoreOptionA];
            SectionAPercentage = scoreMap[ScoreOptionB];
        }
        //Section B Set Score & Percentages
        if (ScoreOptionB != null && PercentageOptionB != null) {
            var ScoreValueB = ScoreOptionB.getValue();
            var valuePercentageB = PercentageOptionB.getValue();
            SectionBScore = scoreMap[ScoreValueB];
            SectionBPercentage = percentageMap[valuePercentageB];
        }
        // Section C Score & Percentages 
        if (ScoreOptionC != null && PercentageOptionC != null) {
            var ScoreValueC = ScoreOptionC.getValue();
            var valuePercentageC = PercentageOptionC.getValue();
            SectionCScore = scoreMap[ScoreValueC];
            SectionCPercentage = percentageMap[valuePercentageC];
        }
        // Calculations
        var Section1Score = (SectionAScore * SectionAPercentage);
        var Section2Score = (SectionBScore * SectionBPercentage);
        var Section3Score = (SectionCScore * SectionCPercentage);
        var averagescore = (Section1Score + Section2Score + Section3Score);
        // Set Average Score Value
        FORM_CONTEXT.getAttribute("dp_decimal").setValue(averagescore);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`exampleFunction error`, error);
        HELPERS.displayErrorMessage(error);
    }
    finally {
        console.log(`exampleFunction finally`);
    }
}
}
```

I am expecting the option set value of the score field to be checked to see if it matches one of the ScoreMaps I defined.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

```
SectionAPercentage = scoreMap[ScoreOptionB];
```

You didn't check for `ScoreOptionB` not to be `null`.

## 2

```
SectionBScore = scoreMap[ScoreValueB];
```

You have not checked for `ScoreValueB` not to be `null`.

## 3

```
SectionCScore = scoreMap[ScoreValueC];
```

You have not checked for `ScoreValueC` not to be `null`.

Comment: But say for example in this section " if (ScoreOptionA != null && PercentageOptionA != null) {
            ScoreOptionA.getValue();
            PercentageOptionA.getValue();
            SectionAScore = scoreMap[ScoreOptionA];" I did check score Option A not null and get same error.

Comment: @BenDev21 can you change that section to `ScoreOptionA != null && ScoreOptionB != null && PercentageOptionA != null` and try again?